# Error python script in screen session

Tags: python, bash, net-snmp

I have a snmp listener which works perfectly when I run it into a screen bash session manually. Like this :

```
screen bash 
python snmp_listener.py
ctrl A + D
```

**Problem :**

I want to automate this task in shell script like this :

```
screen -dmS snmp bash -c "sleep 10; python snmp_listener.py; exec sh"
```

However, after running my script when I attach my screen with `screen -r` I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snmp_listener.py", line 1, in <module>
    import netsnmp
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/netsnmp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/netsnmp/client.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/netsnmp/client_intf.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/netsnmp/client_intf.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: /home/pi/.python-eggs/netsnmp_python-1.0a1-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg-tmp/netsnmp/client_intf.so: undefined symbol: netsnmp_memdup
$
```

Anyone know why it doesn't work only with my shell script ?

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your execution to a single string or .sh file eg:

```
screen -m -d -S snmp python snmp_listener.py

cat pyrun.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 python snmp_listener.py
 # ^^ content of pyrun.sh
screen -m -d -S snmp ./pyrun.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `screen` pro but i don't think this is `screen` related.

- Are you starting both of your variants with the same privileges?
- Have you tried comparing the environments? (e.g. calling `env > /tmp/thescriptenv`)
- Have you tried to run other python scripts in the not-working variant?

Why do you want to run those commands in a `screen` session? If you just want to aggregate logs or keep the session running on logout - http://supervisord.org/ would be a better alternative (IMO).